# Create count column based on multiple criteria

Tags: pandas

I have a df that looks like:

```
          date  value
0   01/01/2020      2
1   01/01/2020      3
2   01/01/2020      0
3   01/01/2020      4
4   02/01/2020      1
5   02/01/2020      3
6   02/01/2020      8
7   02/01/2020      4
8   03/01/2020      0
9   03/01/2020      0
10  03/01/2020      1
11  03/01/2020      0
```

How do I create another column which is a count of the value not equal to zero and have the same date.  My desired output would look like:

```
          date  value   count
0   01/01/2020     -2       3
1   01/01/2020      3       3
2   01/01/2020      0       3
3   01/01/2020      4       3
4   02/01/2020      1       4
5   02/01/2020     -3       4
6   02/01/2020      8       4
7   02/01/2020      4       4
8   03/01/2020      0       1
9   03/01/2020      0       1
10  03/01/2020     -1       1
11  03/01/2020      0       1
```

so for 01/01/2020 there are 3 records not set to 0 so 3 would be returned for every record for the count column where date equals 01/01/2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['Count_nonzero'] = df['value'].ne(0).groupby(df['date']).transform('sum')
```

---

```
print(df)

          date  value  Count_nonzero
0   01/01/2020      2              3
1   01/01/2020      3              3
2   01/01/2020      0              3
3   01/01/2020      4              3
4   02/01/2020      1              4
5   02/01/2020      3              4
6   02/01/2020      8              4
7   02/01/2020      4              4
8   03/01/2020      0              1
9   03/01/2020      0              1
10  03/01/2020      1              1
11  03/01/2020      0              1
```